# Exceptions to 3/8x24 for coaster axle threads?

Tags: axle

Is there such a thing as a contemporary coaster hub that uses 10x1 or 3/8x26? Trying to figure something out without the bike in front of me.

Comment: Do you mean a coaster *brake* hub with derailleur gears?

Comment: No, he's asking about axle threads. The first number is the axle diameter, 3/8 inch or 10mm. The second is threads per inch for imperially sized axles or thread pitch (peak-to-peak spacing) for metric axles.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to say there isn't a fringe case on an old or rare specialty brand hub, but all I've ever seen and worked on have always had 3/8 24tpi axles.  I believe some Sturmey-Archer internal gear hubs use something different, but I thought I remembered it being 13/32 or something.